# jQuery - TypeError: $(...).sortable is not a function

Tags: jquery, serialization, jquery-ui-sortable

I have this code and it doesn't already work. Few days ago it worked, but not any more. And I don't remember what can I have changed...

```
 $( ".guardarorden" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
});

$(document).ready(function(){


    $(function() {
        $( "#ordename" ).sortable({
          placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
          cursor: 'move',
          opacity: 0.5,
          activate: function( event, ui ) {
            $('.guardarorden').removeClass('hidden');
          },
          update: function(event, ui){
            var nuevoOrden = $(this).sortable("serialize"); // Here is my problem!!!
            alert(nuevoOrden);

            $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
              return 'Si has realizado cambios, asegurate de guardarlos antes de abandonar la página...';
            });
            $( ".guardarorden" ).click(function( event ) {
                event.preventDefault();

              $.post('guardaorden/'+nuevoOrden, {list: nuevoOrden},function(data){

                    }, 'json');
              $(window).off('beforeunload');
              alert("Orden guardado correctamente. Aunque esto sería mejor con un mensaje de error típico");
              location.reload();
              //alert("guardado con éxito!")             
            });         
          }
        });
        $( "#ordename" ).disableSelection();
      });
});
```

I don't know why `var nuevoOrden = $(this).sortable("serialize");` is not a function. Any idea?

**EDITED**

I think it is something about jquery-ui. I load every script in my main page like this:

```
{{ HTML::script('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js')}}
{{ HTML::script('js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap-multiselect.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap-slider.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/sisyphus.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}
{{ HTML::script('/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js')}}
{{ HTML::script('/js/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js')}}
{{ HTML::script('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js')}}
```

But I've tried loading manually the last one in the page where I have the problem and it works... but only sometimes (I don't understand). The first time it works good but then I have the error message.

If I delete `{{ HTML::script('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js')}}` from my page and reload the page in my browser, and then I put `{{ HTML::script('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js')}}` again in my page and reload it again, it works. Until I change the page. When I come back, it doesn't work again... :(

**EDIT 2**

Is there any uncompatibility between jQuery-ui and CKEditor?? If I delete `{{ HTML::script('/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js')}}` and `{{ HTML::script('/js/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js')}}` there are no problem!!

Comment: Any reason you can't use `$( "#ordename" ).sortable("serialize");`? Have you tested what `this` is?

Comment: have you by any chance removed the reference to jquery ui?

Comment: @karthikr: Would it not error out on the `$( "#ordename" ).sortable({` line toward the top if that was the case?

Comment: @jwatts1980 I'm using `$( "#ordename" ).sortable("serialize");` to get the data I want to use (its order)

Answer (score 1):

The order of loading Jquery and Jquery-UI is most likely wrong. Try Loading Jquery first then Jquery-UI last.